# First post bounty-style

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Many first posters will ask there question, not entirely sure how SE style works. I think most first posters think it's a forum style, and there is no follow up. If a user is posting a question on SP.SE, or even any SE site, they usually create their account for that one reason, to ask a single question. A lot of the times the question is valid and hasn't been asked before, but the great answers that get posted never seem to reach to accepted answer status.

Here's my suggestion to that. I was thinking it may be interesting to have a bounty-style first-post approach. Make every first-post a bounty style, where in 5 days the most upvoted post will win the 'accepted answer'. This can be completely overidden by the first poster if he/she so chooses. This will allow the accepted answers to be more abundant, and SP.SE will have a more completed question:answer feel.

This will have an added benefit for regulars to welcome first posts. It will encompass a more helpful attitude for first time users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume a poster asks a question about something which can be solved in at least 3 different ways depending on specific factors. 2 of these 3 ways gets submitted but in fact it's the 3rd un-submitted answer which would actually fix it. But people upvote the 2 other ways because they in theory should help fix it. The poster tries both submitted ways but none of them help, leaving no submitted answer marked as the answer.

So even though the poster writes in a comment that the highest voted answer did not solve the issue, this answer would still be marked as the answer after a certain period of time.

6 months later a person stumbles upon the above post because this person faces the exact same issue as the poster and sees that 1 of the 2 answers has been marked as the answer. This marked answer does not help this person either.

It creates confusion and can be misleading.

Comment: I never disregard the other answers just because it's not marked as answered. In theory every answer could work. No one will know without feedback if their answer works for the original poster. The point is, most first posters will never leave feedback or mark any answers. But that is indeed a downfall.